Chrome extension redirect not working on a specific account / computer - cached redirect?
My Chrome extension uses declarativeNetRequests to detect and redirect specific URLs when the user enters them in.
In an earlier version, I implemented dynamic rules in a server worker file, i.e. I was using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules to add a rule (it depended on a variable elsewhere in the file).
In a more recent version of the extension, I changed the flow of how the extension / redirects work to simplify things. Namely, I moved away from doing the above and now simply use a rules.json file which is referenced in manifest.json. In the latest version of the extension, all code relating to the previous dynamic use of updateDynamicRules has been commented out or removed.
The desired, simpler redirect seems to work in general for multiple users (including the device where I do dev work), except when I test it on my other device using a different Google email address, i.e. different Chrome profile. It's almost as if my other device has a cached version of the extension or rules - there's evidence it's still trying the redirect from my earlier version.
Things I've checked:

The other device is using the latest version of the extension
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the extension
There is only the live, from-the-store version of the extension on the other device, not a development version
I have restarted Chrome
I have restarted the device

Any guesses as to what might be going on? Is there a way to check which declarativeNetRequests are active?

I am now pretty sure something weird is happening with caching relating to the background service worker. Even if I completely change the service worker script file, the changes won't reflect when I refresh (or uninstall+reinstall) the dev extension and try it out. I've found chrome://serviceworker-internals/?devtools and have tried to hit "Unregister" on this service worker script, but still nothing.

Delete _metadata folder in the extension's folder. It contains the index for DNR.

Tried that, but it doesn't solve the bug. I've also looked at the file in the _metadata folder that gets regenerated, and can confirm that it seems to correctly reflect the latest version of the static rules. But the discrepancy is still that the extension acts differently on different devices

Open chrome://policy and see if there's ExtensionSettings with runtime_blocked_hosts inside.

No, don't see anything of that sort
